# Can't find information on working with user-selected cells

Tags: excel, vba

Good day! Which way to dig to understand how to work with user-selected cells?

For example: there is a range of vertical cells 1 2 3 4 5. I select them and use a macro to transfer them to a horizontal view.

I know how to do this using the built-in functions of excel itself. But I can't find examples of work with user-selected cells. If you record a macro, then it works with the originally selected cells.

Answer (score 0):

The user-selected range is available in Selection.

For example:

```
Sub TransposeSelectionToNextColumn()
    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, Selection.Rows.Count).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Selection)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found working code

```
    Sub Selection1()
Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim DestRange As Range
 
    Set SourceRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select the range to transpose", Title:="Transpose Rows to Columns", Type:=8)
    Set DestRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select the upper left cell of the destination range", Title:="Transpose Rows to Columns", Type:=8)
 
    SourceRange.Copy
    DestRange.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

It remains to understand how to delete the selected cells with rows.

Comment: This answer shows how to ask the user to select cells. This is different from your question about "user-selected cells", which means that the cells are already selected. You should either change your question or accept my answer below.